# Replace nested pattern matching with "do" for Monad

Tags: haskell

I want to simplify this code

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Network.HTTP.Types
import Data.Text

getJSON :: String -> IO (Either String Value)
getJSON url = eitherDecode <$> simpleHttp url

--------------------------------------------------------------------
maybeJson <- getJSON "abc.com"
case maybeJson of
  Right jsonValue -> case jsonValue of
      (Object jsonObject) -> 
        case (HashMap.lookup "key123" jsonObject) of
          (Just (String val)) -> Data.Text.IO.putStrLn val
          _ -> error "Couldn't get the key"

      _ -> error "Unexpected JSON"
  Left errorMsg -> error $ "Error in parsing: " ++ errorMsg
```

by using do syntax for Monad

```
maybeJson <- getJSON "abc.com/123"
let toPrint = do 
                Right jsonValue <- maybeJson
                Object jsonObject <- jsonValue
                Just (String val) <- HashMap.lookup "key123" jsonObject
                return val
case toPrint of
  Just a -> Data.Text.IO.putStrLn a
  _ -> error "Unexpected JSON"
```

And it gave me 3 errors:

```
src/Main.hs:86:19:
    Couldn't match expected type `Value'
                with actual type `Either t0 (Either String Value)'
    In the pattern: Right jsonValue
    In a stmt of a 'do' block: Right jsonValue <- maybeJson


src/Main.hs:88:19:
    Couldn't match expected type `Value' with actual type `Maybe Value'
    In the pattern: Just (String val)
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      Just (String val) <- HashMap.lookup "key123" jsonObject


src/Main.hs:88:40:
    Couldn't match type `Maybe' with `Either String'
    Expected type: Either String Value
      Actual type: Maybe Value

Even when I replace 

    Just (String val) <- HashMap.lookup "key123" jsonObject
```

with

```
String val <- HashMap.lookup "key123" jsonObject
```

I'm getting another similar error about Either:

```
Couldn't match type `Maybe' with `Either String'
    Expected type: Either String Value
      Actual type: Maybe Value
    In the return type of a call of `HashMap.lookup'
    In a stmt of a 'do' block:
      String val <- HashMap.lookup "key123" jsonObject
```

How do I fix those errors?

Comment: I don't understand the code. What is `maybeJson <- getJSON "abc.com"` supposed to be in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So every line in a do expression for a Monad must return a value in that Monadic type. Monad is a typeclass here, not a type by itself. So putting everything in a do Monad is not really a sensible statement.

You can try your code with everything wrapped in a Maybe monad.
Assuming you've fetched your JSON value:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}

import Data.Aeson
import Network.HTTP
import qualified Data.Map as M
import Control.Applicative
import qualified Data.HashMap.Strict as HM

--------------------------------------------------------------------
main = do
    maybeJson <- return $ toJSON (M.fromList [("key123","value")] :: M.Map String String)
    ioVal <- return $ do -- The Maybe monad do expression starts here
        maybeJson <- Just maybeJson
        jsonObject <- case maybeJson of
            Object x -> Just x
            _ -> Nothing
        val <- HM.lookup "key123" jsonObject                                                                                                                         
        return val 
    putStrLn $ show ioVal
```

Once we start working in the Maybe monad, every expression must return a `Maybe Something` value. The way the `Maybe` monad works is that anything that is a `Just something` comes out as a pure `something` that you can work with, but if you get a `Nothing`, the rest of the code will be skipped and you'll get a `Nothing`.

This property of falling through is unique to the Maybe monad. Different monads behave differently.

You should read up more about Monads and the IO monad here: http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Introduction_to_IO

You should read more about monads and what they really help you do:
http://learnyouahaskell.com/a-fistful-of-monads 
(You should work through the previous chapters and then get to this chapter. Once you do, you'll have a pretty solid understanding of what is happening).

I also think your HTTP request is screwed up. Here's an example of a POST request that you can use.

```
import qualified Network.HTTP as H

main = do
    postData <- return $ H.urlEncodeVars [("someVariable","someValue")]
    request <- return $ H.postRequestWithBody "http://www.google.com/recaptcha/api/verify" "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" postData                    
    putStrLn $ show request
    -- Make the request
    (Right response) <- H.simpleHTTP request 
    -- Print status code
    putStrLn $ show $ H.rspCode response
    -- Print response
    putSrLn $ show $ H.rspBody response
```

UPDATED:
Use the following to help you get a JSON value:

```
import qualified Data.ByteString.Lazy as LC
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as C
import qualified Data.Aeson as DA

responseBody <- return $ H.rspBody response
responseJSON <- return (DA.decode (LC.fromChunks [C.pack responseBody]) :: Maybe DA.Value)
```

You'll have to make a request object to make a request. There are quite a few helpers. I meant the post request as the most generic case:
http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HTTP-4000.0.5/docs/Network-HTTP.html

Comment: thanks. why do you think http request is screwed up? first of all, it is a get request. and your version is more complex, isn't it?

Comment: I don't think that will compile. And you'll have to convert the response which is a string to a ```Lazy ByteString``` or a ```ByteString``` to work with ```Aeson```. Updated the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can't easily simplify that into a single block of do-notation, because each `case` is matching over a different type. The first is unpacking an `either`, the second a `Value` and the third a `Maybe`. Do notation works by threading everything together through a single type, so it's not directly applicable here.

You *could* convert all the cases to use the same monad and then write it all out in a do-block. For example, you could have helper functions that do the second and third pattern match and produce an appropriate `Either`. However, this wouldn't be very different to what you have now!

In fact, if I was going for this approach, I'd just be content to extract the two inner matches into their own `where` variables and leave it at that. Trying to put the whole thing together into one monad just confuses the issue; it's just not the right abstraction here.

Instead, you can reach for a different sort of abstraction. In particular, consider using the `lens` library which has prisms for working with nested pattern matches like this. It even supports aeson nateively! Your desired function would look something like this:

```
decode :: String -> Maybe Value
decode json = json ^? key "key123"
```

You could also combine this with more specific prisms, like if you're expecting a string value:

```
decode :: String -> Maybe String
decode json = json ^? key "key123" . _String
```

This takes care of parsing the json, making sure that it's an object and getting whatever's at the specified key. The only problem is that it doesn't give you a useful error message about why it failed; unfortunately, I'm not good enough with lens to understand how to fix that (if it's possible at all).

Comment: That do block could be all in the IO monad and you could get behaviour similar to the original program by using failing pattern matches in `<-` and `let` statements. Of course, this doesn't let you recover from errors and is probably not the best way to do things.

Comment: I'd like not to use lens for now as it is a third-party library, it's not a part of Haskell.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are in the IO monad, all the `<-` are going to assume that you are dealing with IO operations. When you write

```
do 
    Right jsonValue <- maybeJson
    Object jsonObject <- jsonValue
```

you are saying that jsonValue must be an IO action just like maybeJson. But this is not the case! jsonValue is but a regular `Either` value. The silution here would ge to use a do-block `let` instead of a `<-`:

```
do 
    Right jsonValue <- maybeJson
    let Object jsonObject = jsonValue
```

However, its important to note that in both versions of your code you are using an irrecoverable `error` to abort your program if the JSON parsing fails. If you want to be able to collect errors, the basic idea would be to convert your values to Either (and then use the monad instance for Either to avoid having lots of nested case expressions)

Comment: `maybeJson :: Either String Value`.

Comment: @Zeta: ack, you are right. However, the point still stands if you fix it and swap my `maybeJSON` for `getJSON`. Not sure if its worth fixing the answer though, given how I'm not a fan of `error`-ing out like that